# SwiftUI communication between AppDelegate and ContentView()

Tags: swiftui, cloudkit, remote-notifications

I have a silent remote notification coming in on a SwiftUI app. It is not picked up by the UNUserNotificationCenter, but rather, by the old AppDelegate didReceiveNotification func. What is the solution for notifying ContentView() that a change has occurred? An ObservableObject in AppDelegate?

Answer (score 2):

You can declare a store which conforms `ObservableObject` in the AppDelegate and set it as an environment object to the ContentView.

```swift
// AppDelegate.swift
// in the class
let store = Store()

// in the applicationDidFinishLaunching(_:) method
window.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: contentView.environmentObject(store))
```

```swift
// ContentView.swift
// in the struct
@EnvironmentObject var store: Store
```

The environment object is a reference so you can pass the value into it. Same to using `ObservableObject`. When you finish updating just call `objectWillChange.send()` or mark the property to @Published. And ContentView will be updated after notified.